# Is there an elegant way of doing this using regex?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I need to do a search and replace of variable-like patterns that can occur one or more times within a string. I started out doing the following that works fine:

```
String str1 = "Hello $$(var)";
String regex = "$$(var)";
str1.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(regex), " world");
```

This correctly produces `"Hello world"`.

But I found out that these "variables" could potentially contain literal strings as in the following case:

```
String str2 = "Hello $$(var_AndUniverse)";
```

So now I need a solution where the result for the previous is `"Hello world_AndUniverse"`.

This is a simplistic case. These inputted strings will potentially be thousands of characters long and contain one or more variables with each variable occurring one or more times.

I can figure out a brute force method of using `indexOf()` methods and creating a new string by looping through the entire string, but I am wondering if there is an easier way of doing this using regex and the `replaceAll()` method or maybe a `Pattern`/`Matcher` solution.

Comment: You probably don't want to do this with regex. Use a proper parsing/substituting solution with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I think you should probably implement your own parser. Regex and (what appears to be) markup don't go along nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work by using a capture group to capture everything after *var* and before the ending parenthesis.

```
"Hello $$(var) $$(var bar)".replaceAll("\$\$\(var([^\)]*)\)", "world$1");
```

Should result in:

```
Hello world world bar
```

Parts of the Regex

- `\$\$\(var`: Literal **$$(var**
- `([^\)]*)`: Capture group capturing any character but **)** 0 or more times.
- `\)`: Literal **)**.

### [REY - Test Regex](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/ma4ovb)

Comment: Awesome! Works great.

Answer (score 0):

To find replace all sequences of `$$(any text)` you can use

```
"Hello $$(var) $$(foo bar)".replaceAll("\$\$\([^)]+\)", "world");
```

Which will print

```
Hello world world
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think so. I suppose that with String str1 = "Hello $$(var) $$(var bar)"; (notice I changed the value) he expects "Hello world world bar" as result.